# How to split maven-surefire-plugin execution to two separate executions?

Tags: java, maven, surefire

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
[...]
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*JSFTest.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <!-- intentionally empty to override configuration above -->
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*JSFTest.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

My custom `<execution>` has to run all JSF-related tests in the container. Unfortunately it doesn't find any tests. Looks like `<includes>` doesn't work. While `<excludes>` effectively exclude these tests during phase `test`. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out on how to do both integration testing and testing in the same project.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing

My preference is the `maven-failsafe-plugin`

Comment: Link is not useful anymore and there is no summary in the answer. Would you care to expand?

Answer (score 2):

More as a note to self: ;-)

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>none</exclude>
<excludes>
```

An empty excludes doesn't work.